# Search User keyword in full file path and according to searched result give output directory or filename

Tags: python

I have full file path and user search the keyword if user input is in basefilename print full file name.

if searched keyword is folders part then print path untill that searched path

Example:
filepath='D:\ABDCD\Desktop\old.net\BestchPring\Vs.net\CommanUsegftrol.ascx.cs'

if user search desk:
output should be D:\ABDCD\Desktop

if user search Comman:
output should be:D:\ABDCD\Desktop\old.net\BestchPring\Vs.net\CommanUsegftrol.ascx.cs

```
import os
searchtext='cs'
filepath='D:\ABDCD\Desktop\old.net\BestchPring\Vs.net\CommanUsegftrol.ascx.cs'
fle=filepath.lower()
searcheddata=fle.find(searchtext.lower())
if searchtext in os.path.basename(filepath):
    print("File: ",filepath)
elif(searcheddata!=-1):
    lastdir=fle[searcheddata:].find('\\')
    print("Folder: ",filepath[:searcheddata+lastdir])
else:
    print("File And Folder Both Not Found")
```

Comment: And what exactly is the question or issue? Reading user input? Algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understood, but i think this is what you want:

```
filepath='D:\ABDCD\Desktop\old.net\BestchPring\Vs.net\CommanUsegftrol.ascx.cs'

def findpath(searchtext):
    path = os.path.normpath(filepath)
    while path != "":
        path, folder = os.path.split(path)
        if searchtext.lower() in folder.lower():
            return os.path.join(path, folder)
    return "Not found"
```

Results:

```
In [1]: findpath("des")
Out[1]: 'D:\ABDCD\Desktop'

In [2]: findpath("comman")
Out[2]: 'D:\ABDCD\Desktop\old.net\BestchPring\Vs.net\CommanUsegftrol.ascx.cs'
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it helps you, may you accept it as the correct answer, so it can also help others?

Comment: but when file or folder not searching it did not returning any value

Comment: What do you mean by file or folder not searching?

Comment: findpath("dsjhddddjjdf") this will do not return anything

Comment: it returns: "Not Found" for me... What is the expected behavior?

Comment: you can change the default value returned on line: `return "Not found"`

Comment: i am using python 3.7     this will findpath("dsjhddddjjdf") does not returning value

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct, below code is what you need.

```
def filter_by_keyword(directory, pattern):
    root = ...
    if os.path.dirname(directory):
        for path, subdir, files in os.walk(root):
            for fn in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
                print('Matched variant found in "{}", fn: "{}"'.format(path, fn))
```